# executing blocks stored in NSMutableArray with a parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to understand blocks a bit more.

I have these definitions:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * callBacksOnSuccess;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^callBackSuccessWithUIImage) (UIImage *) ;
```

When the image download finishes I do this in the completion block and things are fine

```
UIImage *coverImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
callBackSuccessWithUIImage(coverImage);
```

Now I'd like to be able to do same for all callback blocks stored in the callBacksOnSuccess NSMutableArray but I don't know how to approach this.

I'm trying a for in loop, but that's not working most likely because of the ambigous id class definition:

```
UIImage *coverImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
for (id callBackBlock in callBacksOnSuccess) 
{callBackBlock(coverImage);}
```

Please push me towards the right approach.

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all:**

Consider to use a `typedef` to your blocks, in order to ease the syntax:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)(UIImage*); //declare this somewhere
```

Then, you can easily iterate through your array like this, executing each block inside it:

```
UIImage *coverImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
for (MyBlock block in callBacksOnSuccess) {
    block(coverImage);
}
```

You can even use the new type in your property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyBlock callBackSuccessWithUIImage;
```

Comment: thank you! works like a charm. so surprised to see typedef as the solution.

Comment: Glad to help! The `typedef` actually just made everything much easier to understand and read. Your problem was because you were declaring the `callBackBlock` variable inside the `foreach` loop as the type of `id`, who does not support calls like `block()`. If you had declared the variable as `void (^callBackBlock) (UIImage *)` in the for loop, it would have worked in the same way, but just a lot 'uglier'

Comment: yes, I knew the id was the problem, just couldn't figure out what to do about it. Blocks are awesome, I just need a bit more time to understand them fully.